# How to mirror keyframes and their angle?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

Lets say im animating a leg, and i want to make a same perfect animation on the second leg,but since just pasting would look weird,is there any way i can paste keyframes and make them be different angle? like changing Z 1 to Z -1 (different side)

Comment: hello, could you please show some pictures to make it easier to understand?

Comment: Like copy pose, paste x flipped, but for animation?